# Using arithmetic operation in jq adding values doesn't work

Tags: bash, jq

I would like to enter few fields into json file from the script in bash, where I create fresh file if empty and then adding values from FOR loop. I have following statements

```
JSFl="/tmp/test.json"
Port=1050
For Srv in $(cat /tmp/servers); do
  NodeNm=$(grep "$Srv" /etc/hosts | awk '{print $2}')
  IPn=$(grep "$Srv" /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}')
  if [ -s $JSFl ]; then n=""; else n="-n"; fi
  Args='--arg S "$Srv" --arg Node "$NodeNm" --arg IP "$IPn" --arg P1 $Port'
  jq $n $Args '{"$S": [{"Node": $Node, "PubIP": $IP, "Port1": ($P1|tonumber), "Port2": ($P1-1), "Port3": ($P1+2)}]}' "$JSFl" > tmp.json && mv -f tmp.json "$JSFl"
done
```

I should get myfile.json to be like following

```
{
    "Comp1": {
      "Node": "C1VM1",
      "PubIP": "1.2.3.4",
      "Port1": 1050,
      "Port2": 1049,
      "Port3": 1052,
    }
}
```

but I keep getting errors:

```
jq: error (at <unknown>): Invalid numeric literal at EOF at line 1, column 5 (while parsing '$Port')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the input file. Also, defining args that way is very error prone if any of the variables contains a space character.

Comment: Also, I don't see a loop in your code

Comment: Using a string to store Args runs afoul of [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Don't do that; args should be an array. Your current code treats the quotes inside the args string as literal arguments, not as syntax.

Comment: BTW, you can use `jq ${JSFl:+-n}` to pass `-n` only if `JSFl` contains at least one character. No need for a `$n` variable at all.

Comment: With every loop iteration, you are overwriting the content of your file, you are never extending it

Comment: Thanks @knittl I've updated the question.  My understanding is that my `jq` adds new record and lists existing records from json file, and then I overwrite them in each iteration, but obviously something is not written properly

Comment: @DenisZ, honestly, it looks like you've edited this so much you should have just accepted an answer and asked a new, distinct, entirely separate question. We frown on changing a question in a way that makes existing correct answers invalid, and making a question about looping when it previously wasn't is _definitely_ in that category.

Comment: That said, the smarter way to do this is to do the looping _inside jq itself_, not in bash.

Comment: (I'm trying to remember what we call questions that change to encompass newly-discovered issues after they're answered; "shape-shifting" comes to mind, but googling [meta] shows that's not the right term; _whatever_ the term, though, it's unfair to the people who are trying to help you to move the goalposts, and also can make your question too broad to be on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this does not work.

```
Args='--arg S "$Srv" --arg Node "$NodeNm" --arg IP "$IPn" --arg P1 $Port'
```

You cannot nest quotes in the shell; the quoted quotes are not only included literally but also don't do any good as far as quoting their contents. So any spaces in those parameter expansions will result in extra arguments to `jq` causing an error, and even if you get past that, your `jq` argument values will have literal quotation marks in them. See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

It's not clear that you need to put the arguments into a variable at all, but if you're going to do so, you need to make it an array:

```
Args=(--arg S "$Srv" --arg Node "$NodeNm" --arg IP "$IPn" --arg P1 "$Port")
```

which you then pass to `jq` like this to preserve the separation:

```
jq "${Args[@]}" ...
```

Second, `jq` is strongly typed; values passed in via `--arg` come in as strings (whether you put quotes around them in the shell or not), and you can't do arithmetic on strings.

You could explicitly convert to a number, like so:

```
jq --arg PS "$Port" '$PS|tonumber as $P1| do math with $P1'
```

Or you could use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`, which tells `jq` to parse the argument as JSON and therefore interpret a numeric string without any *literal* quotation marks around it as an integer (again, shell quotes don't change anything):

```
jq --argjson P1 "$Port" 'do math with $P1'
```

Third, you're doing this in your `jq` query expression:

```
{ "$S": ...
```

And that doesn't do what you think it does: an object key in quotation marks is just a literal string; `"$S"` is just a two-character key consiting of a dollar sign and an S, with no relation to the argument variable named `$S`. To use a nonliteral value as the key, you need to lose the quotes and put it in parentheses:

```
{ ($S): ...
```

Comment: `Args` may not be _typical_, but it's also not wrong. POSIX sets out the namespace containing at least one lowercase character as reserved for applications, so this is within the standard-defined convention.

Comment: Indeed, it's not wrong, unlike the plethora of all-caps names we usually see. Mixed-case is absolutely fine, just . . . as I said above . . . unusual. :)

Comment: (Could also get rid of `$n` altogether in favor of `${JSFl:+ -n }`)

Comment: The more important thing this isn'd addressing -- the OP's code is using `tonumber` only in one place, when the port is used in three; it's the other two spots where they haven't converted `$P1` to an integer that are throwing the error the question is most immediately about.

Comment: Maybe prefix their existing jq code with `($P1|tonumber) as $P1num |`, and then change the `$P1` to `$P1num`? Or follow peak's suggestion of using `--argjson` to assign `P1`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used `($P1-1|tonumber)` `(($P1|tonumber)-1)` `((($P1|tonumber)-1))` and none worked, so I'm not sure how to convert it to number eventhough port is number, always

Comment: `($P1|tonumber)-1` should work fine. Maybe it failed because of the other problem with the quoting?

Comment: See heavily-edited answer . . .

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy I put Args in array as you suggested and it did write all keys properly, but $Srv variable as parent key.  I'm also doing something wrong as only the last records are preserved

Comment: @DenisZ, once you've got the way you're passing arguments in fixed, I don't see why `--argjson` wouldn't work. Maybe take a look at `bash -x yourscript` logs -- that'll show effects of hidden characters (like newlines), will distinguish between literal and syntactic quotes, &c.

Comment: Thanks @MarkReed with $Args as an array it calculated ports properly, and no error, now only key $Srv gets written as '$S'  not treated like variable, and I have to somehow be able to write more records in

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right, now even passing --argjson works well.

Comment: ...oh, I see you're using `"$S"` _inside_ the jq. Yeah, that won't work; those double quotes explicitly make it a string with the literal text `$S`.

Comment: To use a variable (or any other non-literal expression) as the name of a key in a `jq` object, get rid of the double quotes and use parentheses instead: `($S): ...`

Comment: Thanks @MarkReed that worked '($S)'   only in parentheses without gave an error.  But what is a proper way to write directly to `.json` file? Do I need to pipe it via tmp file and overwrite it?   I'm still getting only last record written in file

Comment: I don't know where you are supposed to be getting multiple records? Your posted script just sets some variables once.  Your JQ query doesn't actually do anything with its input at all

Comment: @MarkReed I've updated question with for loop.  I get them actually from another jq, and my idea is to write them to separate json file, with 3 ports so I can then go to check if ports are open.

Comment: Move the `>tmp.json && mv` to the `done` of the loop instead of doing it inside the loop, otherwise you're overwriting the file every time

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to do arithmetic on $Port, you should consider using —-argjson instead of —-arg when passing it in. Otherwise you would have to use `tonumber` as appropriate.

Comment: This is true, but it's not even _close_ to being the whole of the OP's problem. They're currently passing `--arg IP '"1.2.3.4"'` and `--arg Node '"C1VM1"'` _with literal double quotes as part of the value_ for the reasons given in BashFAQ #50. I suppose one _could_ switch to `--argjson` to make the quotes be treated as JSON syntax, but it'd be much better to fix the shell syntax and stick with `--arg`.

Comment: using --argjson gives me an error `jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson`

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems unnecessarily complicated and wouldn't work, even if you fix your jq invocation; your target file is always overwritten.

```
file="/tmp/test.json"
port=1050
while read -r srv; do
  awk -v srv="$srv" '$0~srv{print $1,$2}' /etc/hosts | {
    read -r ip name
    jq -n \
      --arg srv "$srv" \
      --argjson port "$port" \
      --arg PubIP "$ip" \
      --arg Node "$name" \
      '{($srv): [{$Node,$PubIP,Port1:$port,Port2:($port-1),Port3:($port+2)}]}'
  }
done < /tmp/servers | jq -s 'add' > "$file"
```

This approach has several benefits over the original solution (but is still not perfect; `read` is slow and whitespace could be problematic):

- It reads ip and name with a single `awk` command (no need for grep + awk)
- It passes each variable to jq instead of interpolating parameters (incorrectly) as argument list
- The port is passed as number, not a string. This avoids having to filter it through `tonumber` in your jq program
- Each loop iteration outputs the object for a single server
- The full output of the loop is slurped and then merged into a single object

If you have control over the format of `/tmp/servers`, I'd suggest converting it to a JSON array, then you wouldn't even need a shell loop and could do everything with a single `jq` invocation.

---

The following might be an idea too:

```
jq -R \
--argjson port 1050 \
--argjson servers '["srv1","srv2"]' \
'
select(test($servers[]))
|[splits("\\s")]
|{(.[1]):[{Node:.[1],PubIP:.[0],Port1:$port,Port2:($port-1),Port3:($port+2)}]}
' /etc/hosts
```

`--argjson servers ...` could be replaced with `--slurpfile ...` and then `$servers[0]` instead of `$servers`.

Comment: Thanks @knittl that seems much more efficient and simplified.  I do actually retrieve Servers PublicIP from another json file, which I then  check and partially match for LocalIP and NodeName from /etc/hosts, but I was strugling with enetering records into the new json file